# TFS: PublisherNotFoundException when trying to create a subscription for "rm"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk, ms-release-management

On-premises TFS 2015 u2. I want to create an HTTP service hook subscription for a release creation event. As directed [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/events#ms.vss-release.release-created-event) and [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/hooks/subscriptions), I'm sending a POST request to

```
http://tfs.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/MyCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0
```

with the following JSON:

```
{
"publisherId": "rm",
"eventType": "ms.vss-release.release-created-event",
"resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
"consumerId": "webHooks",
"consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
"publisherInputs": 
{
    "projectId": "aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
},
"consumerInputs":
{
    "url": "http://someserver/somefolder/"
}
}
```

I get back the following error message:

```
{
"innerException": null,
"message": "No publisher could be found with id \"rm\".",
"typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.WebApi.PublisherNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"typeKey": "PublisherNotFoundException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 4501
}
```

And indeed, if you request a list of publishers, there's only one, with ID "tfs". There's no "rm" publisher there. Requesting the same subscription from the "tfs" publisher yields an "unknown event" error.

Do I have to enable that publisher somehow? Is it supported in on-prem TFS? If so, since which version?

Would it hurt Microsoft to annotate their TFS REST API docs with supported versions, like the rest of their API docs do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A publisher is a service that publishes events to service hooks. In TFS 2015 update2, if you request a list of publishers, you will not get publish ID with "rm". It's not support for TFS2015 for now.

Moreover, actually the resource version for `rm` should be 3.0

```
"resourceVersion": "3.0-preview.1",
```

Comment: Only in hosted TFS, I presume. Good to know, thanks. Please consider documenting that, as well as other API differences between hosted and on-prem TFS.